# c++ inheritance with default constructor

Tags: c++

I have just started to learn inheritance in c++. I have question about it. Here is my code:

```
class employ
    {
    int xelfasi;
    string manqana;
public:
    employ(istream&is)
{
    is >> xelfasi >> manqana;
}
~employ()
{

}

};
class manager : public employ
{
int bonusi;
manager(int x)
{
    bonusi = x;
}
```

};

which gives me an error saying: no default constructor exists for class "employ".
I don't really get why I have to make an default constructor. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`manager` basically contains an `employ` (though in the form of inheritance). So to be able to construct a `manager`, you need to be able to construct the contained `employ`. So you have to either provide a default constructor for it, or construct it explicitly by calling an existing constructor.

To construct it explicitly, you have to do something like this:

```
manager(int x): employ(#some istream here#)
{}
```

Comment: so you mean that when i create manager object it contains xelfasi and manqana from class employ and to "fill" those things i have to create default constructor?